# Why does clang++ fail to defer symbol resolution when encountering a public static floating-point member variable of a templated class?

Tags: c++, templates, clang++

When a `public`, `static` floating-point member variable of a templated class is used, clang fails on compilation (when warnings are treated as errors) instead of deferring symbol resolution to link time.  This is not the case for a similarly scoped integer member variable, where clang correctly fails at link (if no definition of the class is provided).

GCC treats floating-point and integer member variables equally: in both cases it fails at link.  The behaviour is compared [here](https://godbolt.org/z/s6Mo41zYv), at Compiler Explorer.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
void func(T& p_arg) {
    std::cout << p_arg << std::endl;
}

template <class T>
struct Foo {
    static const int s_default_int;
    static const double s_default_dbl;
    T my_T;
};

int main() {
    using t_Foo = Foo<short>;

    // GCC and clang fail on link
    func(t_Foo::s_default_int);

    // GCC fails on link
    // clang fails during *compilation*
    func(t_Foo::s_default_dbl);
}
```

Clang:

```
<source>:23:17: error: instantiation of variable 'Foo<short>::s_default_dbl' required here, but no definition is available [-Werror,-Wundefined-var-template]
    func(t_Foo::s_default_dbl);
                ^
<source>:11:25: note: forward declaration of template entity is here
    static const double s_default_dbl;
                        ^
<source>:23:17: note: add an explicit instantiation declaration to suppress this warning if 'Foo<short>::s_default_dbl' is explicitly instantiated in another translation unit
    func(t_Foo::s_default_dbl);
                ^
1 error generated.
```

GCC:

```
<source>:19: undefined reference to `Foo<short>::s_default_int'
```

Is this a compiler bug in clang?  Is there a workaround?

Comment: Clang fails with an error only because you used `-Wall -Werror`. It is a warning, not an error.

Comment: I have seen few questions that better qualify to be closed as a typo than this one. One compiler is passed flags, the other is not. It was never a fair comparison.

Comment: @sweenish, my apologies, I neglected to keep the flags up to date while re-arranging the windows in my initial test case for presentation purposes.  I didn't notice because the behaviour was unchanged.  I have updated the linked example.

Comment: @user17732522, that's fair, but why is there no warning for the static int member?   The thrust of the question is meant to be "why is the treatment unequal?".  The specified flags make the discrepancy clear.  I also aspire to have warning-free compilation, which may be more a matter of personal taste.

Comment: @mccutchm I am not sure why Clang considers `s_default_int` different. Variables of `const` integral or enumeration type has some special rules (e.g. in relation to constant expression evaluation), but I don't really see why that should suppress the warning for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the warning is just Clang trying to warn you that you are likely to get a linker error later on. Here is a Clang dev's opinion on the warning and how to work with it : https://github.com/dealii/dealii/issues/3705#issuecomment-1175596077

If `Foo` is explicitly instantiated in a cpp file, the compiler won't see it yet and will issue the warning. In this case, you can declare an explicit instantiation with something like `extern template struct Foo<short>;` so the compiler assumes that an explicit instantiation exists somewhere else.

If `Foo` is not explicitly instantiated later, then the warning seems correct and a definition for the static members should be added to the header.

The reason GCC doesn't complain during compilation is that there is no error local to this code. The error only occurs when taking all translation units as a whole during linking. Clang is issuing a warning that something might be wrong later, but isn't directly complaining that something is broken within the translation unit. Since as far as I know GCC doesn't have an equivalent warning, the behaviour can't be duplicated.

As to why Clang warns for `s_default_dbl` but not `s_default_int`, I'm not sure. It seems like the warning should apply to both cases. I speculate that it may be related to the fact that a const static data member of integer type can be treated as a constant expression, but float members can't. Ex. `static const int s_default_int = 10;` is okay and you could use it as a constant expression such as `char my_array[Foo<int>::s_default_int];` but `static const double s_default_dbl = 42.0;` is not allowed (you'd need to make it `constexpr` explicitly). The compiler may be confused treating `s_default_int` as a constant expression and assuming the class doesn't need a definition for the member to be useful. It may be an exception to the warning to avoid some false positives.

Comment: I think your intuition is correct.  The compiler promotes an integer const to constexpr, hiding the lack of clarity in where the final definition of the variable should be taken from.  Using constexpr for both those variables precludes all the warnings.  And a final templated re-declaration of each of the variables makes them available for use in main (updated example at https://godbolt.org/z/fxEazcnvY).   Thanks!